# Endianness of "IBM PC" byte order?

Tags: endianness

I looked at [the Wikipedia article on endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) and it doesn't mention anything about this type of byte order (which is what photoshop asks me about when opening RAW files). Which is it?

Comment: All 3 of you are right, i suppose it should have been obvious... Answer goes to the one with lowest rep i guess. (Doesnt hurt that it's the most straightforward!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IBM PC == x86 which is mentioned in the article (uses LO HI byte order a.k.a. little endian)

Answer (score 3):

That Wikipedia article says that X86 is little-endian. Is there something else you're asking and I'm missing it?

Comment: I didn't make the connection between IBM PC and X86 until just now!